# Can we implement the low quality flags to delete posts after a certain number of flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, flags, low-quality-posts

Can we implement the low quality flag to be like the abuse or spam flags.
So if a certain number of low quality flags are made [(say 6)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99558/is-it-possible-for-a-post-to-be-actually-flagged-six-times) on a post (whether it be a questions or an answer) the post is deleted?

This would also relieve *close vote and delete vote queues. *which is a much discussed topic.

[1, 2, 3...test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971)
[What can be done about the massive Close Votes queue on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/what-can-be-done-about-the-massive-close-votes-queue-on-stack-overflow)
[Reset the close vote queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208680/reset-the-close-vote-queue)
[Huge close votes review queue on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow)
[Daily close votes queue limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit)

related: [Should Stack Overflow be more restrictive about new user registrations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations)

Comment: So users with 15 rep can delete things rather than 20000 rep as required currently?

Comment: @RobertLongson what about raising that rep?

Comment: @Yvette: Then you get the same thing as [this suggestion of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273410/255554).

Comment: Also suggested on MSO: [Fixing the disconnect between VLQ and Triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323946)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the fact that you only need 15 reputation to start flagging posts I don't think any number of flags should lead to immediate deletion of posts.

There are simply too many options for abuse here.

Deletion has the potential for destroying content. It needs context and experience to correctly judge if a post can be deleted. The Low Quality Queue is doing its job there and I don't see a huge backlog on that.

I can imagine that at most numerous Low Quality flags influence how the post is presented. It could be removed from the front-page, not being bumped when edited, maybe not shown in search results until the flags have been cleared. But I believe down votes serve as a better mechanism for that.

Comment: What about raising the rep to make those flags?

Comment: @Yvette but that lowers also the feeding of the queue, assuming you want to keep the queue around .. if not that flag rep needs to go way up where I then wonder how people will find such posts, so it gets complicated fast, I'm afraid.

Comment: yes that is true, very true.